# React JS socket.io-client performs multiple connections to socket.io server

Tags: reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to build a web app that allows users (no registration needed) to join rooms and play a simple game. I have a `HomePage.js` that utilizes `CreateRoom.js` and `JoinRoom.js` and the two ultimately lead to `RoomLobby.js` where all the *magic* is supposed to happen. Based on whether a user is the owner of a room or not, the user will see a different lobby. Room data is stored in MongoDB.

My issue is that whenever I create a room or join a room (through my API) and enter the room lobby with that user, the backend console is repeatedly logging `New client connected l4Er0kKsczrGRlMUAACC`, with the latter being a different socket ID for every time.

Here is my server setup:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./api/routes');
const cron = require('node-cron');
const { Room, Participant } = require('./model');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3001", // Client URL
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});

app.use(express.json()); // For parsing application/json

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3001' // Allow only your React app to access
})); // Enable CORS for all routes

// Middleware to attach io to the req object
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.io = io;
  next();
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI)
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New client connected', socket.id); // <--- This one repeats

  socket.on('joinRoom', (roomCode) => {
    socket.join(roomCode);
    console.log(`A user joined room: ${roomCode}`);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
});

app.use('/api', routes);

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Here is how I handle connection in my React app component, firstly with a `socket.js`:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

// "undefined" means the URL will be computed from the `window.location` object
const URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL : 'http://localhost:3000';

export const socket = io(URL, {
    autoConnect: false
});
```

And in my `RoomLobby.js`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { socket } from '../service/socket';

import ContentCopyIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ContentCopy';

const RoomLobby = () => {
  const [roomData, setRoomData] = useState(null);
  const [iconSize, setIconSize] = useState('default');
  const [dotCount, setDotCount] = useState(1);

  const { roomId } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const userId = location.state?.userId; // Get userId from state
  const userName = location.state?.userName; // Get userName from state

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRoomData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/room/${roomId}`);
        setRoomData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching room data', error);
        navigate('/');
      }
    };

    fetchRoomData();
  }, [roomId, navigate]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Establish the socket connection when the component mounts
    socket.connect();

    // Join the room once roomData is available
    if (roomData && roomData.roomCode) {
      socket.emit('joinRoom', roomData.roomCode);
    }

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {   
    // Set up event listeners
    socket.on('gameStarted', (updatedRoom) => {
      setRoomData(updatedRoom);
    });
  
    socket.on('nextTurn', (data) => {
      setRoomData(prevData => ({ ...prevData, currentTurn: data.currentTurn }));
    });
  
    // Return a cleanup function to run when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, [roomData]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (roomData && roomData.roomStatus === 2) {
      // Disconnect the socket when the game is over
      socket.disconnect();
    }
  }, [roomData]);

  const startGame = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/start-game', { userId: userId, roomCode: roomData.roomCode });
      setRoomData(prevData => ({ ...prevData, roomStatus: 1 }));
      // Emit a socket event if using WebSockets
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error starting the game', error);
    }
  };

  const playTurn = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/play-turn', { userId: userId, roomCode: roomData.roomCode });
      // Update UI based on response or wait for WebSocket event
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error playing turn', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    {/* Layout */}
  );
};

export default RoomLobby;
```

With this code, both the network log in my browser and the server log show repeating (different) connections whenever I create or join a room to enter its lobby.

I have looked at multiple solutions online and asked ChatGPT, but nothing seems to work in my case. In one case, the issue was differing versions of socket.io between client and server, but in my case, both the `socket.io-client`-package on the client side and `socket.io`-package on the server side are updated to the latest version.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

[This documentation page](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-installation/) confirmed my suspicion that the problem was a version mismatch between `socket.io` on the server on `socket.io-client` on the client.

Apparently `npm install socket.io` did not install the latest version on my computer, so I had to use `npm install socket.io@latest` to get it. After that, it registers connections as it should.